# user_for_paper_trail defined in controller not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, versioning, paper-trail-gem

```
  class DemandControlsController < Shared::BaseController
     def user_for_paper_trail
       current_user.try(:username)
     end
  end
```

I'm trying to define the user_for_paper_trail method directly in this DemandControls controller; I've also tried to define it in Shared::BaseController but the whodunnit column in my versions table keeps showing up as NULL. Does it specifically have to be defined as a method in the ApplicationController class?

Comment: Why are you trying to re-define it? Also, you have it improperly defined. You're returning `username` which is a string but the method expects the return value to be a user object. https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/paper_trail/1.5.0/symbols/PaperTrail::Controller/user_for_paper_trail

Comment: @Nathan I'm redefining it because I want to store `current_user.username` and not `current_user.id`. In the paper_trail docs, they say you can override that method to return a string of whatever you want. Here is their example:

  `def user_for_paper_trail`
    `logged_in? ? current_member.id : 'Public user'  # or whatever`
  `end`

Comment: Try putting something else in there other than `current_user.try(:username)`. For example, try putting in a string like `"testing...123"`. If that works your problem is not with the `use_for_paper_trail` method but `current_user.try(:username)` Likely you will need to use something like: `current_user.try(:username).present? ? current_user.username : "Guest"`

Comment: @Nathan yeah i tried that, still didn't work :( I added an `abort` even and it didn't even trigger that method

Comment: @Nathan i figured out at least it's because `Shared::BaseController` isn't inheriting from `ActionController::Base`. I wonder what module in `ActionController::Base` I need to require. I rather not include all of `ActionController::Base` just to get this working...

Comment: Good debug suggestion @Nathan